# FA Icon in placeholder of an input?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, reactstrap

As I saw in the documentation, Font Awesome has a way of put an icon in an input placeholder, doing something like this:

```
  <Input placeholder='&#xf002; Search' />
```

This is what I get:

[image]

> No matter what code I put after &#x, it always renders the same icon.

I'm working with `ReactJS` and `Reactstrap` library. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot (sorry 4 my english)

Comment: The right way is put the font-family "FontAwesome" in the input where i want see the icon. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it this way, because the font family of the input field is using an English font. Font Awesome uses it's own font file.

One way to implement this would be to use a positioned `<i>` element:

```
<div class="container">
  <label><b>Username</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
  <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 40px;
  color: gray;
}
```